# bootstrap 4 hide element using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to hide some elements on the page that use the class 'd-md-block'.
Because of the important on the class definition i can not use jquery hide/show functions.

Example, i want an element to be visible on desktop

```
<div id="test" class="d-none d-md-block">Welcome User!</div>
```

The visibility works as expected.
Then when a user clicks a button i want to toggle the visibility (this fails due to the d-md-none class)

```
 $('#btn').on('click',function(){$('#test').hide();});
   $('#anotherBtn').on('click',function(){$('#test').show();});
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: how do say it fails due to `d-md-block class`?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam it actually fails due to `d-none` class it has `display: none !imporatant` property

Comment: yes correct is due to d-none class but this is not the point... any idea who be able to work with the jquery visibility functions and these classes ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple work around for showing and hiding the element in bootstrap-4. As `d-none` class assigns `display: none !imporatant` property, you can simply add and remove this class via JavaScript to simulate the `hide` and `show` operations. Something like this:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#test').removeClass('d-block')
});
$('#anotherBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('#test').addClass('d-block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="test" class="d-none d-md-block">Welcome User!</div>
<button id='btn'>Hide</button>
<button id='anotherBtn'>Show</button>
```

Comment: i imagine that i could that, but i am migrating from v3 to v4 and there is a lot of code already written, i don't want to rebuilt everything and if i follow this logic  means that i have to find all the places that show/hide elements and replace the code, also animation won't work such us slideDown, slideUp (yes on the done event i could add/remove the class but specially on the show it will not animate)

Comment: Then use `d-block` if there are multiple elements. That will work for you. It will leave the `d-none` class unchanged and everything will be same for you

Comment: no it didn't i am still trying with all the !important tags to fix it thought javascript.
It is a slide menu, that is visible only on desktop and also by default is not expanded (this requires custom style display: none !important to overwrite the d-md-block class)
when a user clicks to the expand icon the i slideDown/Up the menu
so only the remove of d-block is not fixing my issue